# Flux and Normal Derivatives

Tags: modeling, mathematics

Could someone please clarify the difference between flux and normal derivatives?

I am studying PDE's and I came across Neumann Boundary condition (In this condition, the value of the **normal derivative** is given).  I then came across the following: For a steady state thermal process, the Neumann condition describes a prescribed **heat flux**.

Comment: This seems similar to the explanation [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24593/the-concept-of-flux/24600#24600).

Answer (score 0):

The 1-D energy balance on an object with no internal heat generation is

$$k \frac{\partial ^2T}{\partial z^2} = \rho \tilde{C}_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} $$

A viable boundary condition (BC) for energy flow into an object is written as

$$-k A\left. \frac{dT}{dz}\right|_{boundary} = \dot{q}$$

Consider an solid object with heat flow entering from the right. The BC says, the heat flow (J/s) that enters is conducted through the object.

This condition applies regardless of steady state or not. In steady state, $\partial T/\partial t = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are a few types of boundary conditions:

1. Dirichlet BC
2. Neumann BC
3. Cauchy BC
4. mixed BC
5. Robin BC

The most usual are 1 and 2, while the rest are essentially combinations of the first two. I'll limit the description to the first two. For an example I will use a 2nd order ODE (because most people are more familiar that PDEs), before explaining the flux.

Assuming you have the following equation:
$$m\ddot{x}+ c\dot{x} + x =0 $$
then in order to solve it you need two boundary conditions. All the following are valid boundary solutions:

- $x(t=0) = 0, \; x(t=1)=2$  (two Dirichlet BC)
- $x(t=0) = 0, \; \dot{x}(t=0)=1$ (one Dirichlet and one Neumann BC)
- $\dot{x}(t=0)=1, \; \dot{x}(t=1)=0$ (two Neumann BC)

So Neumann BC are associates with derivatives of the variable, while Dirichlet are associated with the values of the variable.

Returning to the concept of the **normal derivative** and the **flux**. A **normal derivative** is a directional derivative taken in the direction normal (that is, orthogonal) to some surface in space.

The most easy example understand this is probably heat transfer/diffusion. You can think of a rod or a plaque that you apply some heat (imagine a small torch) at one end. The temperature at that end is not fixed, however the heat supply (or heat **flux**) is, so in that situation you want to apply a Neumann BC. The **normal derivative** has to do with the fact that the heat travels **perpendicular** to the boundary surface (rod crosssection / plaque side).